# How to implement this cache control policy in PHP?

Tags: php, cache-control

Serve the new content only if the file has changed since last visit.

How do I implement that?

**UPDATE**

Sorry not to mention it earlier,but the requested resource is web page which is requested directly,not an image.

Comment: Is it a static `.html` page or a `.php` page? Browsers will not cache dynamic pages (`.php`, `.asp` etc)

Comment: It's `.php`,can we change that behavior?

Comment: I don't believe so, you'll have to write the output of your script to an `.html` file and serve that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a trick borrowed from rails and append the last file modification time to the include:

```
$fileName = 'image.jpg';
$httpLink = $fileName . '?' . filemtime( $fileName );
echo '<img src="', $fileName, '" alt="blah" />';
```

This will output a link like

```
<img src="image.jpg?1002412" alt="blah" />
```

Then when the file changes, the query string will also change and the browser will request the "new" file i.e.

```
<img src="image.jpg?1003622" alt="blah" />
```

Alternatively you could keep a local log of file revisions and read the revision number from a database rather than the filesystem, which may be marginally faster (and save filesystem reads, although it's not significant difference - dependant on db vs web server load).

Comment: Hey, what a nifty idea! `filemtime` is also pretty easy on performance. Nice!

Comment: This will work **much** better if you use PATH_INFO instead (browsers might be picky if the URL doesn't end with an extension).

Comment: But this won't work for me,because the page is requested directly, and what I want to cache is the page,not image.

Comment: also, *please*, don't **ever** use `.jpg`, that's a DOS evilness. Use full `.jpeg`.

Comment: @Lo'oris used this in production with no problem, PATH_INFO doesn't provide a modified file time. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @user198729 could you update your question then? You don't mention what type of data you're serving.